# jQuery hide record title if record not found

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one list of entries, and these entry shorted by alphabetically, now I want to display My Entry & Other Entry by clicking on button.

In this code suppose I have one button on click that I want to show My Entry (see class="class_my") with class="item" & class="title". I can do this but in second case(id="h") have no class="class_my", for that I do not want to display anything (class="item" & class="title")

```
<li id="g" class="item">
<a name="g" class="title">G</a>
   <ul>
       <li>                   
       <a href="?page_id=242&amp;fid=9&amp;entry=due7ya" class="class_other">Grovy Roy</a>
       <a href="?page_id=242&amp;fid=9&amp;entry=due7ya" class="class_my">Gova Patel</a>
       </li>
   </ul>
</li>
<li id="h" class="item">
    <a name="h" class="title">H</a>
       <ul>
           <li>                   
           <a href="?page_id=242&amp;fid=9&amp;entry=due7ya" class="class_other">Honey Roy</a>

           </li>
       </ul>
    </li>
```

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly, all items will be hidden initially, and when your click "My Entry" you want to show items that have one item `.class_my` inside them. Same with "Other Entry". Is that correct?

I'd suggest looking for the class, then using [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to find the parent item:

```
$(".item").hide(); // All them are hidden in the beginning
$("#my_button").click(function() {
    $(".class_my").closest(".item").show();
});
```

If that's not what you're trying to achieve, please clarify (edit your question with more info). Show also what you've tried so far, so we can help you spot what's going wrong.

**Update:** if all items are shown in the beginning, and the button will hide some of them, move the "hide all" to inside your function:

```
$("#my_button").click(function() {
    $(".item").hide(); // Hide all them, and...
    $(".class_my").closest(".item").show(); // ...show only the ones you want.
});
```

Comment: Can you plese help m here http://jsfiddle.net/uZAt9/1/    I have write your code in document ready function and its not hide H title & data

Comment: My code is to show them, not to hide them. Will all them be initally hidden or shown? (From your comment, looks like the answer is "shown"; I'll update my answer then)

Comment: Oh, I didn't see it. Good then! I updated it anyway, showing both ways it could be done...

Answer (score 1):

Try with this code. (btn is your button).

```
btn.click(function(){
    $('.class_my').closest('.item').show();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>StatockOverflow</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.class_my').hide();
            $('.class_my').parent().hide();
            $('.class_other').hide();
            $('.class_other').parent().hide();
        })
    function showanchor(obj) {


        if ($($(obj).parent()).children("ul").children("li").children('a.class_my').length > 0)
            $($(obj).parent()).children("ul").children("li").show();
        $($(obj).parent()).children("ul").children("li").children('a.class_my').show();


        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <ul>
    <li id="g" class="item">
    <a name="g" href="javascript:void(0);" class="title" onclick="showanchor(this);">G</a>
   <ul>
       <li>                   
       <a href="?page_id=242&amp;fid=9&amp;entry=due7ya" class="class_other">Grovy Roy</a>
       <a href="?page_id=242&amp;fid=9&amp;entry=due7ya" class="class_my">Gova Patel</a>
       </li>
   </ul>
</li>
<li id="h" class="item">
    <a name="h" href="javascript:void(0);" class="title" onclick="showanchor(this);">H</a>
       <ul>
           <li>                   
           <a href="?page_id=242&amp;fid=9&amp;entry=due7ya" class="class_other">Honey Roy</a>
           <a href="?page_id=242&amp;fid=9&amp;entry=due7ya" class="class_my">Gova Patels</a>

           </li>
       </ul>
    </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```